# Pycharm automatically closes a program, python idle doesnt

Tags: python, tkinter, pycharm, python-idle

When running a tkinter program in the standard python idle program the window displays and you are able to interact with it, yet running the same program in pycharm causes the program window to flash up briefly then close.

I'm assuming its to do with the mainloop, what do you need to modify in your code to prevent the program from automatically closing when running in pycharm

An excert from my code follows

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter
from tkinter import Text, Tk, ttk
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import sys
import os

class GUI:
    def __init__(self, root):


....

def main():
    global label   
    root = Tk()
    root.title(" My program")
    root.geometry("550x330+600+300")
    mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (39, 39, 39)  # background color
    root.configure(bg=mycolor)

    gui = GUI(root)

main()
```

Update : After a bit of mucking around, partly due to my code not being the best (rookie), I've managed to get it to work. For anyone interested heres the modification:

```
from tkinter import *
import csv
from csv import DictReader
import sys
import os

class GUI:
def __init__(self, master):
    self.master = master
    master.title(" My Programs")
    master.geometry("550x330+600+300")
    master.iconbitmap('logo.ico')
    mycolor = '#%02x%02x%02x' % (39, 39, 39)  # background color
    master.configure(bg=mycolor)
```

....... Most of the above is program set up stuff but shown 
    MAIN CODE HERE

```
root = Tk()
gui = GUI(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Works now as expected

Comment: Did you look here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27637197/tkinter-window-closes-automatically-after-python-program-has-run-in-pycharm

Comment: I did, but didnt think it was relevant to my program. Mine has a gui window with data entry boxes and search button etc. I'm open to being proven wrong though :)

Comment: So did you add root.mainloop() after your event handlers (if you have any)?  What was the result?

Comment: being a basic program i dont have any event handlers, the program simply searches a CSV file for a particular string and displays the fields in various text widgets, nothing flash

Comment: Have you tried adding root.mainloop()?  I think that link I posted above shows a solution to a problem that is identical to yours.  Regardless of the items on the form, the answer, which is marked as accepted, states to run window.mainloop().  You have called your TK() instance root instead of window, so I think you should try root.mainloop().  I don't actually use pycharm, so I can't test, but I don't see any reason yet why your use case is any different than the link above.

Comment: I'll give it a try, thanks. I normally just use the python idle program which works fine with the program how it currently stands but pycharm seems to be better with showing issues with the code, hence I'm using it to fault find :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has a `-i` startup option which cause Python to enter interactive move when the program finishes, instead of exiting.  IDLE executes code as if one entered `python -i file.py` at the terminal.  This allows one to interactively explore the live gui by entering code in the Shell.

From this question and the one referenced by flyingmeatball, it appears that PyCharm does not use or simulate `-i`.  So one must finish a tkinter program with root.mainloop to see anything.  Unless one adds a button to quit the mainloop without destroying the application, one will not be able to interact with interactive statements.  (Again, this is completely based on what has been posted on SO, as I have no experience with PyCharm.)